# Why is java.util.Set not Assignable From java.lang.Iterable?

Tags: java, set, iterable

When I call `Set.class.isAssignableFrom(Iterable.class)`, it returns `false`.

Nevertheless, [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), `java.util.Set` is listed as a subinterface of `java.lang.Iterable`. Hence my confusion. You can even try it out in a single line of code:

```java
System.out.println(Set.class.getName() + " is " + ((Set.class.isAssignableFrom(Iterable.class)) ? "" : "NOT " ) + "assignable from " + Iterable.class.getName());
```

it prints `java.util.Set is NOT assignable from java.lang.Iterable`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `isAssignableFrom` wrong.

As [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) say, `isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)` "determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter". So `cls` would be Set.class, and the full syntax would be:

`Iterable.class.isAssignableFrom(Set.class)`.

...which, indeed, returns `true`.